# PHP exec on windows opens cmd window

Tags: php, exec

I'm running PHP on win XP and I'm using `exec()` for some stuff in my program but every time the `exec()` is running a `cmd.exe` window is opened for a few seconds on the server. How can I make it run in the background ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix the command with `start /B`.

```
$process = popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/function.exec.php#86329

Answer (score 1):

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run('yourprogpath', 0, false);
```

Windows only.

EDIT - I think Fraxtil's answer is probably better if it works across windows and unix.

Comment: My answer doesn't work on Unix, actually. The `start` command is Windows-specific. The comment I linked to does provide an OS-agnostic solution, though.

Comment: O.k. Probably worth noting that it also opens a file pointer to the process that you can read and write to (could be handy). Will it wait until the procces completes or is it asynchronous? Couldn't really work it out from docs.